# can't start winForm from a thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I am trying to start a winForm from a thread, but when i do so, the form show but none of the labels are loaded ( the background where they should be is white ) and the form is frozen.

I've tried it with some other winForms that i know that work just fine and it still doesn't seem to work ? Has anyone encountered this problem ?

I know the question is vague but there isn't really any specific code that I could give to help understand the problem.

Comment: IIRC Creating forms on multiple threads can work, but it can make the code *particularly* complex and prone to subtle cross-thread issues. I strongly suggest sticking to one UI thread here. In any event, some kind of example code that shows the issue would help hugely here.

Comment: Are you sure your form has a message loop that it's currently running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `Message Loop` runs on UI thread only. And when a control or window is created in any other thread, it cannot access that message loop. And thus, cannot process user input.

To solve this, try creating a window from UI thread and create a thread from that window to do whatever you want to do in different thread.

Answer (score 2):

UI thread is supposed to be one.
Then, I suggest you to open your form calling a method of your original form thread, like in the example below:

(To test it just create an empty form called `MainForm` and paste this code in it)

```
public delegate void OpenFormDelegate(string txt);

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var button1 = new Button();
        button1.Text = "Run for 5 secs and open new window";
        button1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        t.Start();
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // sleep for 5 seconds
        this.BeginInvoke(new OpenFormDelegate(OpenNewForm), "Hello World !");
    }
    public void OpenNewForm(string text)
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        f.Text = text;
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is related to thread access, when the new form is created it will not be able to access the UI thread. Use the main thread to create the form and new thread to process the infomation.