# Should I use the STA or MTA apartment state for a winforms window running on a new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to open a window on a new thread, and I'm wondering if I should mark the thread as STA or MTA? I know that threadpool threads run as MTA, but they're typically not associated with any UI elements. Do winforms windows need to run as STA?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344835/cant-start-winform-from-a-thread. Short answer: Don't do it. A user can only manipulate one form at a time anyway. If you need processes running in the background, you can spin up a thread to do that, or use a `BackgroundWorker` object.

Comment: A thread that creates a window *must* be STA.  The clipboard, drag+drop and the shell dialogs require STA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127240/858670) for this SO question, explains STA vs MTA very well.

I would recommend running it as STA if it is a winforms window regardless, otherwise you will run into undefined behavior territory even if you get it to compile.